# How to fix and/or catch HIB error on the Coral Dev Board

Tags: python, tpu, google-coral

I am working with the Coral Dev Board running an image classification model using the Coral Camera.  While running the script, I will randomly get the following error

````
E driver/mmio_driver.cc:254] HIB Error. hib_error_status = 0000000000000008, hib_first_error_status = 0000000000000008```
````

This error does not throw an exception, so I have two questions:

1. Is there a permanent fix for this error?  I see a reference to this issue with regards to the Mini PCIe Accellerator ([here](https://coral.ai/docs/m2/get-started/#troubleshooting-on-linux)), but my application is using the dev board.
2. As a workaround, is there a way to detect this error so it can be handled properly?